# Obtain Core Data persistent NSSQLiteStoreType store accessible as NSIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsincrementalstore

Apple Core Data [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Introduction/Introduction.html) says that iOS's built-in SQLite Store (`NSSQLiteStoreType`) is an incremental store.

However, if I create a store of this type (by adding it to a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`) it exists apparently as an instance of the (iOS-internal) class `NSSQLCore` and `[store isKindOfClass: NSIncrementalStore.class]` returns `NO`.

Is it possible to obtain from iOS an instance of an SQLLite Store that can be accessed as an `NSIncrementalStore`?

I'd like to add caching to a custom `NSIncrementalStore` and employ a wrapped SQLite Store for that purpose, if that's possible (straightforward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

At best you could create your own NSIncrementalStore implementation that duplicates what the built in store does but that would be a tremendous amount of effort and would violate the design intentions of the of the store.

The internal design of the SQLite file that Core Data uses is considered internal and **will** change without notice.  It is not recommended that you reverse engineer it.

Comment: Too bad. So `NSSQLiteStoreType` returns an "incremental store". I wouldn't consider manipulating `NSSQLCore`'s tables directly.  (BTW, good advertisement for your book, of which I'll now get a copy.)

Comment: After having read your book I have posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898966/prefer-property-accessors-or-kvc-style-for-accessing-core-data-properties) follow-up question.